# How to convert a loop into an array in ColdFusion to remove duplicates?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm a ColdFusion newbie and I tried to remove duplicates from the output of the script below with the group-attribute in the `<cfoutput>`-tag but somehow that doesn't work:

```
<cfoutput query="show_books" group="titleno">
```

So I tried to group duplicates via SQL:

```
GROUP BY books.ean
```

But unfortunately, that doesn't work neither.

So I think now, I need to convert the loop below to an array or a list to write the results of the first search into an array/a list, sort it, then remove the duplicates and do the final output from that array/list. But I don't have a clue how to do that in ColdFusion. So any help is appreciated!

The script is from a website presenting books. When you open the detail page of a book, you see other books written by the same author/s at the bottom of that detail page. The problem is, it works fine with just one author. Also with two or more authors, but only (and that's the crux) if they haven't written more than one book together. So e.g. we have a team of three authors, that have written four different books together we see 12 books in the output instead of four... :-(

Here is the code:

```
<cfloop query="title_data">

    <!-- query database -->
    <cfquery name="show_books" datasource="#database#" dbtype="ODBC">
        select * from books, books_publisher, books_mapping
        where books.ean <> '#ean#' AND
        books_publisher.publisher_id = #title_data.publisher_id# AND
        books_publisher.partner_id = books_mapping.adrno AND
        books.titleno = books_mapping.titleno AND
        (books.visibility = 1 OR books.visibility = 2 OR books.visibility = 20 OR books.visibility = 95 OR books.visibility = 102 OR books.visibility = 107)
        order by books.title asc, books.ean asc
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput query="show_books"> 

        <!-- load publisher -->
        <cfquery name="show_mapped" dataSource="#database#" dbtype="ODBC"> 
            select * from books_mapping 
            WHERE titleno = #show_books.titleno# AND
            (role = '1' OR role = '2')
            order by books_mapping.ranking
       </cfquery> 
       <cfset authorteam = #show_mapped.recordcount#>

        <!-- show title data of books -->
        <table>
        <tr><td>
               <a href="index.cfm?view=3&ean=#ean#"><img src="./covers/small/#cover#" class="shadow"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
               <cfloop query="show_mapped"> 

                  <cfquery name="show_publisher" dataSource="#database#" dbtype="ODBC"> 
                     select * 
                     from   books_publisher 
                     WHERE  partner_id = #show_mapped.adrno# 
                  </cfquery> 
                  <cfloop query="show_publisher"> 
                     <cfset authorteam = authorteam -1>
                     <a href="index.cfm?view=6&author_id=#publisher_id#" class="authors">#publisher_prename# #publisher_surname#</a> 
                     <cfif authorteam neq '0'>|</cfif>
                  </cfloop> 
             </cfloop> 
             ....
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td align="right">#price_eur# EUR</td>
            <td> ...
                <a href="index.cfm?view=3&ean=#ean#" class="further_button">Details</a>
            </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </cfoutput>

</cfloop>
```

Also if there is another way or workaround to remove the duplicated entries in the output it would be of great help for me. I'm open for all kinds of suggestions just to make it work.

Comment: (Edit) Ignoring other issues for a moment A) Please edit your post to describe the relationships of the three (3) tables and include a small data sample.  B) What column(s) identify the author?It is hard to tell since the queries use SELECT *, rather than individual column names.

Comment: I strongly suspect the query and/or filters are either incorrect, or less efficient as they could be. Providing a *small* data sample, and a description of the tables will help us suggest a more efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the primary key values, change this:

```
select * from books, books_publisher, books_mapping
```

to this:

```
select distinct justTheFieldsYouNeed
```

If you do, then keep your query the way it is and use the group attribute of cfoutput to manage your display.

```
<cfoutput query="yourQuery" group="someField">
#groupedData#
<cfoutput>
#ungroupedData#
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Although a `distinct` might help, it could also mask a bigger problem if the query is wrong. I would recommend reviewing the sql first to determine if the join's are even necessary.